# Remove viewport metatag from wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, viewport

I looked everywhere but couldn't find a remove action for the viewport metatag from wp_head() in wordpress. Is it possible to remove it?

Found this article http://circlecube.com/2013/01/adding-viewport-meta-tag-via-wordpress-theme-functions/ which helped me to add my own, but now I have two tags...

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment out the line `add_filter('wp_head', 'viewport_meta');` from your themes's `functions.php`